# Apache optimization needed

Tags: apache-2.2, performance-tuning

What is the best values for "worker" if you have very very high traffic? Like 500M page views per day?

I want to test my server with that much traffic but how can i setup to handle that much traffic and how can i make this test?

Thanks

Comment: @ashwin

Thanks for the link. But what values should I set for maxclient, minspare, maxspere and etc.?

Answer (score 1):

ab is tool from apache for benchmarking your setup. It can simulate hits. Read more from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html